# Mean value of $[x,p]$ on an eigenstate of $x$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, momentum, commutator

The canonical commutation relation states that $$[x,p] = i \hbar\ \mathbb{I}$$
if we imagine to be in a one dimensional space.

If we take the mean value of the commutator over an eigenstate of the position $|x'\rangle$ we get $$\frac{\langle x'| [x,p] |x'\rangle}{\langle x'|x'\rangle} = \frac{\langle x'| i \hbar\ \mathbb{I} |x'\rangle}{\langle x'|x'\rangle} = i \hbar.$$

Now, instead of using the canonical commutation we write the commutator explicitly
$$\frac{\langle x'| [x,p] |x'\rangle}{\langle x'|x'\rangle} = \frac{\langle x'| xp |x'\rangle}{\langle x'|x'\rangle} - \frac{\langle x'| px |x'\rangle}{\langle x'|x'\rangle}.$$

In the first term of the difference the operator $x$ acts on the bra giving the eigenvalue $x'$, while in the second term the operator $x$ acts on the ket giving again the eigenvalue $x'$, then
$$\frac{\langle x'| [x,p] |x'\rangle}{\langle x'|x'\rangle} = \frac{x' \langle x'| p |x'\rangle}{\langle x'|x'\rangle} - \frac{x' \langle x'| p |x'\rangle}{\langle x'|x'\rangle} = 0.$$

I know obviously the second result it's the wrong one. Can someone point the error I'm making in the second calculation?

Comment: The problem is that something like $\langle x|x\rangle$ is not well-defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14116/

Comment: While not a duplicate, [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/604548/157014) also deals with a similar problem.

Comment: Here is a similar discussion on two general operators $A$ and $B$: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/418593/279116